# setvisible function is not working on google map api

Tags: api, dictionary, google-maps-markers

I can try control with checkboxes my map. I search all site and try different ways since two days and I can't.

```
  <div class="xx" onclick="x();"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCA2WMMIAgJiHsnxIsO3mJC3F5vLINgAW&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var markers = [{"title":'Kaya',"lat":'40.8309889',"lng":'39.460643',"icon":'gmi6.png'},...];

window.onload = function () {LoadMap();}

function LoadMap() {
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var styleArray=[.....

var mapOptions={center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.818575, 39.685296),zoom:10,minZoom: 9,styles: styleArray,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i];
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map:map,
    icon:iconBase + data.icon,
    title: data.title.replace("&#39;", "´")});
        (function (marker, data) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
            infoWindow.setContent("<div style='width:250px;min-height:40px;'><a href='" + data.urllink+"'><h4>"+data.title +"</h4><br><img alt='' src='"+ data.image +"' style='width:100%;'></a>"+ data.description + "</div>");
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        })(marker, data);
    }
}


function x() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setVisible(false);
    }
}


</script>

<div id="dvMap" style=".."></div>
```

console log : markers.lenght : 40 ok. , 
markers[i] : [object object] .  I dont understand.

like i am doing one mistake but where or how?

markers[i] is not working or setvisible not working